# How to put text inside border html

Tags: html, css, text, border

```
    #border {
        position: static;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        margin-left: 92% ;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 11px;
        background: white;
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    #text {
        margin-left: 93%;
        z-index: 2;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;  
    }

    <div id="border"></div>
    <div id="text">Users online</div>
```

*I can't post the image here, cuz I have less than 10 reputation, so try to imagine it please. I want to place it's "Users online" inside the border, how should I do this? Thanks.*

Comment: why don't you put it in directly in border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to have an element with a semitransparent background.
Since you are using the `opacity` property on the element with an id of `border`.
The problem here is that `z-index` will not have any effect, if the `position` is set to `static`, which is the default value for `div` elements.

The other thing is, that you should be using a `relative` positioned parent to make your life easier and have more control over the elements since positioned elements will leave the normal document flow and result in new stacking order.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index) you can find good information on the the `z-index` property, stacking and the document flow.

This is one solution to your problem.

```css
body {
  background:black;
}

.holder {
  position:relative;
}

#border {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  right:0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
  right:0;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div id="border"></div>
  <div id="text">Users online</div>
</div>
```

But i would actually try to solve this with a different approach, because i find the above solution a bit to complex and it involves to much positioning, so if all you need is a semitransparent background just make use of the `background` property with an `rgba` value. Here is an example.

```css
.user-panel {
  float:right;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  /* fallback for browser that do not support rgba */
  background: #ccc;
  /* semitransparent background */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
/* clear the float using the pseudo after element */
user-panel:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="user-panel">Users online</div>
</header>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it has helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
position: static;
```

to

```
position: absolute;
```

for `#border`. That way, `border` will be "removed from the flow" (i.e. other elements will ignore it). You may need to adjust the `margin-left` property for `#text` so it properly aligns.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xzdmLt33/1/